# Instances of Actions - Verbs into Nouns

Tags: verbs, derivation, noun

In English, we can take a verb like "swim" and refer to it as a noun in reference to occurrences.  For example,

1. "That was a good swim,"
2. "I have three swims next week."

Is there a similar construct for Latin?
The *infinitive* and the *gerund* come to mine.  But in the first example, "swim" is nominative, so it doesn't fit the usual gerund pattern.  "Natare bonum erat" implies "swimming was good" rather than referring to a particular instance of a swim that was good.

In the second example, "swim" is accusative.  But references I found about the accusative gerunds indicate this was more commonly used for purpose than to refer to instances of occurrence.

Comment: If the verb has a fourth principal part, then you can probably use the fourth-declension verbal noun ending in *-tus;* e.g., *venatus bonus fuit* 'the hunt was good', but I don't think this can be pluralized. Note that in my dialect I don't often here the English version pluralized either.

Comment: Visus (seen) and visus est (he seemed, was seen) exist alongside Visus (4) appearance, visage (also plural.). And Liquor *n,* // Liqueo, make liquid. But generally it needs -esco, -ficio, as a conjugating suffix.  Vis (strength), viresco (strengthen).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is the *-or* suffix that forms abstract nouns, like `amare` -> `amor`.

This probably would not work well with `natare`. I propose `natatio,-onis` . Accoring to [L.S.](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=natatio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), this could convey the meaning of an instance of swimming.

The same suffix *-tio* also forms nouns from other verbs.